# post edit history feature?

Tags: feature-request

during my last question, I edited my post like 6 times to show changes I made in my code to users answering my questions. My edited code became so far from the original that if someone searching for an answer was to look at my last post they wouldn't have even understood what my issue was in the beginning and thus it would not be helpful to them because they might have a hard time determining whether my original problem was anything like their current problem.

Some type of "view edit history" would solve this. Anyone else think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This already exists. If you click on the "last edit date" link on a question or answer, you'll be taken to a page showing the diffs between all revisions of the question.

[Here is the revision history of the question you're referring to.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4414814/revisions)

And here's it in action on this very post:

[image: edit history]

Comment: note:  the "last edit date" link is not actually called "last edit date" ... it will look similar to the above diagram, example:  "edited **1 hour ago**".

Comment: As of today, the entire phrase, "edited on..." is now clickable.