# where did "last edit date" go

Tags: support, edits

I'm trying to determine what edits were made to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980211/how-do-i-search-all-non-virtual-and-virtual-registries-in-vista-win7-et-cetera
by John Saunders

I found [post edit history feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72005/post-edit-history-feature) but I can not find "last edit date" on the page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980211/how-do-i-search-all-non-virtual-and-virtual-registries-in-vista-win7-et-cetera.

Not trusting my eyesight, even Ctrl+F (IE8, win7) could not find "last edit date".

Has this "last edit date" feature been removed?

thnx / gerry (lowry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the revision history for that post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4980211/revisions

You get there by clicking the `edited`[`14 hours ago`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4980211/revisions) just to the left of your name.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exact time (UTC) from the tooltip on the last edited time:

[image: last edited time]