# A malfunctioning or malicious add-on has caused Internet Explorer to close this webpage

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

"A malfunctioning or malicious add-on has caused Internet Explorer to close this webpage."

I got the above message with this response in the IE8 address bar:
res://ieframe.dll/acr_depnx_error.htm#stackoverflow.com,[post edit history feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72005/post-edit-history-feature)

IE8/Windows 7

I'm not sure whether I caused the above error or it is a problem at so.

Here's the IE8 page source FWIW:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ErrorPageTemplate.css">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Webpage error</title>

    <style>
      IE\:HOMEPAGE {behavior:url(#default#homepage)}
    </style>
    <script src="errorPageStrings.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="httpErrorPagesScripts.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="acr.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="BodyLoad();InitRetry();InitHomePage();javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); initMoreInfo('infoBlockID');">
    <IE:HOMEPAGE ID="oHomePage" />
    <table width="730" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

    <!-- Error title -->
        <tr>
            <td id="infoIconAlign" width="60" valign="top" rowspan="2">
                <img src="red_x.png" id="infoIcon" alt="Info icon">
            </td>
            <td id="mainTitleAlign" valign="middle" width="*">
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Internet Explorer has closed this webpage to help protect your computer</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <!-- This row is for HTTP status code, as well as the divider-->
            <td id="errorCodeAlign" class="errorCodeAndDivider" align="right">
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>


    <!-- Error Body -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="likelyCausesAlign" valign="top" >
                <h3 id="likelyCauses">A malfunctioning or malicious add-on has caused Internet Explorer to close this webpage.</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- What you can do -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="whatToDoAlign" valign="top" >
                <h2 id="whatToDo">What you can do:</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- retype address -->
        <tr>
            <td >
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="goHomeAlign" valign="middle">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <img src="bullet.png" border="0" alt="" class="actionIcon">
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <span id="goHomeAddress"></span>
                              <noscript><id id="goHomeNoscript">Go to your home page</id></noscript>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- back to previous page -->
        <tr>
            <td >
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="retryAlign" valign="middle">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <img src="bullet.png" border="0" alt="" class="actionIcon">
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <span id="retryAddress"></span>
                              <noscript><id id="retryNoscript">Try to return to the page you were viewing</id></noscript>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- InfoBlock -->
        <tr>
            <td id="infoBlockAlign" align="right" valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="moreInfoAlign" valign="middle">
                <h4>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); return false;"><img src="down.png" id="infoBlockIDImage" border="0" class="actionIcon" alt="More information"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                           <span id="moreInfoContainer"></span>
                           <noscript><ID id="moreInformation">More information</ID></noscript>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </h4>

                <div id="infoBlockID" class="infoBlock">
                    <p id="errorExplanation">Windows Data Execution Prevention detected an add-on trying to use system memory incorrectly. This can be caused by a malfunction or a malicious add-on.</p>
                    <p id="errorExplanation">Other things you can do:</p>
                    <p id="errorExplanation"><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=124983">Go online to learn about the Data Execution Prevention (DEP) security feature</a></p>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Mmm, I don't think this is on SO's end (I can see nothing on that page that could use a IE add-on - no Flash, no movies...)

Comment: No repro in Win7 x64 in either 32- or 64-bit mode of IE 8.0.7600.16385.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this -- and we don't use anything but basic HTML and CSS, either.

Comment: given the notes here, my best guess is it must have been a win7 and/or ie8 glitch. thnx / g.