# mini-Markdown did not work in a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug report: Using bold markup next to a quotation will not render the text as bold in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78119/bug-report-using-bold-markup-next-to-a-quotation-will-not-render-the-text-as-bol)

I added the following comment to the answer to [post edit history feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72005/post-edit-history-feature):

note: the "last edit date" link is not actually called "last edit date" ... it will look similar to the above diagram, example: "edited **1 hour ago**".

in "edited **1 hour ago**" I use mini-Markdown around
"1 hour ago" but the double asterisks remained ***in the displayed comment***.

I expected to get
edited **1 hour ago**

My best guess is the problem is the quotes
==> "edited **1 hour ago**"
but it's difficult to show that in the above line
because the above line is working as expected.

QUESTION:  is this a bug in the comment module?

thnx /g.